# Proxchains through Tor not working as expected

Tags: tor, privoxy

I trying to do Proxychains with Privoxy and I want to connect this way:

> Me -> Tor -> HTTPS Proxy -> Web

I wrote a Privoxy main config file look likes this:

```
listen-address 0.0.0.0:8118 
forward-socks5 / localhost:9050 . #tor
forward / ip:port #specific proxy
```

The problem is I am still connecting like this:

> Me -> HTTPS Proxy

And my setup is not connecting through Tor.

Maybe the Privoxy main config file needs to change? What am I doing wrong?